# Node.js remoteAddress not working correctly

Tags: node.js, express, http, request

Using node.js (v16.15.1) and Express the code

```
console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress)
console.log(req.socket.remoteAddress)
```

returns in both cases the same address like "::ffff:123.123.123.123"

Problem : This is not the client remote address but the address of my server, what is not really useful.
No proxy, only the usual redirection from port 443 to 5000 which is the server's port.

Some idea to fix this ?

Comment: What does 'redirection port' mean. This is not a standard concept as far as I know. What did you use to forward the traffic?

Comment: "redirection de port" in French, better translation is port forwarding or port mapping. Done with netsh (Windows)

Comment: Ok, what command did you use to forward the port?

Comment: You are right, I removed the port forwarding and directly plugged the server on port 443. Ant this did the trick!. So next step is having the right netsh command. The current one is: netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=123.123.123.123 listenport=443 connectaddress=123.123.123.123 connectport=5000

Comment: And netsh without the 'connectaddress=123.123.123.123' parameter does not fix the problem.

Comment: I don't know much about `netsh` and if it can do a lower-level port mapping. It sounds to me like it just works as a proxy after all. If this is the case, you might be better off using a more traditional proxy like nginx so you at least get headers such as `X-Forwarded-For` which will contain the real user ip.